# React Native Metro infinite 'reload'

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

**Environment**

`"react-native": "0.63.4"`

`node --version: v15.8.0`

When I try to run application on two phones (Android via USB  and iOS emulator) by running following command:

`npx react-native run-android && npx react-native run-ios`

my application launches correctly but on running it shows me infinite reloading. (what I mean by infinite is that message 'Refreshing' shows up then disappears and so on in infinite loop.

[image]

And after a dozen of reloading it ends up with an error.

Here are the errors.

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if you run it in only one device does it work?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and managed to solve it by placing the project folder inside a "tmp" called folder.